# EF Core cannot achieve OR translation dynamically by IQueryable.Where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, orm, ef-core-3.0

```
using (var ctx = new StockContext())
{
    var syms = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };

    return ctx.Assets.Select(x => x.Symbol)
    .Where(symbol => syms.Any(sym => symbol.Contains(sym)))
    .ToArray();  // EXCEPTION: InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Asset>() .Where(a => __syms_0 .Any(sym => a.Symbol.Contains(sym)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
}
```

```
using (var ctx = new StockContext())
{
    var syms = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };

    return ctx.Assets.Select(x => x.Symbol)
    .Where(symbol => s.Contains(syms[0]))
    .ToArray();  // WORKS FINE
}
```

Please see the codes above. I think this is a quite common practice, but I can't even make the first example works.

What I want to achieve is the codes from the 1st example can be translated into:
`SELECT Symbol FROM Assets WHERE Symbol LIKE '%foo%' OR Symbol LIKE '%bar%'`. How come it runs with exception?

p.s. I know that PredicateBuilder may solve this problem. However, can I achieve such easy operation by native EF code? Thanks in advance!

---

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-preview.4.20220.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0-preview.4.20220.10" />
```

Comment: Is `.Where(symbol => s.Contains(syms[0]) || s.Contains(syms[1]))` an option?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, your solution works for static size `IEnumerable`

Comment: @mannok that's not an `OR` either in LINQ to Entities, or Line to Objects. It's an `Any` operation with a `Contains`. It's not treated as multiple `OR`s in either C# or SQL.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using full text search instead? ORMs are meant to map objects to relational results, not act as replacements for SQL. A `LIKE '%abc%'` operation is  *very* expensive as it can't use any indexes to find strings in the middle of other strings. It has to scan the entire table. That's what FTS provides in various databases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The cost of how we search should be take into account. However, before this, I think we should know why such a common operation cannot be compiled by EF first.

Comment: It's not a common operation, especially when wildcards are involved. Even in C#, that's simply not chained ORs. You assumed this should be translated as chained ORs, but that's simply not the case, as `Any` is applied to an *array*, not the entities. To get this translated, EF would have to send that array to SQL somehow, eg with a TVP. The second query is *very* different, as it probably results in a nested query

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, writing an expression tree parser is *hard*, and sometimes you need to unroll it manually to help it. Consider:

```cs
var syms = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };

var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Asset), "x");
var symbol = Expression.PropertyOrField(p, nameof(Asset.Symbol));
Expression body = null;
var contains = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains), new[] { typeof(string) });
foreach (var sym in syms)
{
    var test = Expression.Call(symbol, contains, Expression.Constant(sym, typeof(string)));
    if (body == null) // first
    {
        body = test;
    }
    else
    {
        body = Expression.OrElse(body, test);
    }
}
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Asset, bool>>(body, p);
var results = ctx.Assets.Where(lambda).Select(x => x.Symbol).ToArray();
```

What this does is build the expression tree manually based on the input; it is the equivalent of:

```cs
x => (x.Symbol.Contains("foo") || x.Symbol.Contains("bar"))
```

in this case, but should expand to any number of inputs.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I need some times to digest it!

Comment: Using FTS in SQL and mapping the results using Dapper is probably a better option - it's certainly faster

Answer (score 0):

Test this please ...

```cs
 var syms = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };

 return ctx.Assets.Select(x => x.Symbol)
    .Where(symbol => syms.Any(x => EF.Functions.Like(symbol, x)))
    .ToArray();
```

```cs
            var syms = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };

            var select = ctx.Assets.Select(x => x.Symbol);

            foreach (var item in syms)
                select = select.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x, item));

            var result = select.ToArray();
```

Comment: I have tried this before but no luck :(    `ctx.Assets.Select(x => x.Symbol).Where(symbol => syms.Any(sym => EF.Functions.Like(symbol, sym))).ToArray();` throw `InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Asset>()
.Where(a => __syms_0
.Any(sym => __Functions_1
.Like(
matchExpression: a.Symbol,
pattern: sym)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().`

Comment: Hmm i have another idee... Give me a minute

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Seems the problem comes from `syms.Any()` in `IQueryable().Where()`

Comment: hmmm ... I think my last edit will not work... It will be an AND instead of an OR... I think @Marc_Gravell is right.

Comment: Seems the update is not achieving what we want. You are chaining the Where clause which in other words it is a `AND` operation instead of `OR`. Your codes can represent in SQL like `SELECT Symbol FROM Assets WHERE Symbol LIKE 'foo' AND Symbol Like 'bar'`